# What is the stripe webhook to listen to get notified about subscription item deletion

Tags: stripe-payments

In my usecase i have multiple plans under same interval added as a subscription item under single subscription as documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/multiple). Now when i cancel a single subscription item from a subscription, does stripe provide any webhook with particular event to notify that a subscription item is cancelled?. Read through all the webhooks events documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types) but couldn't find a relevant one. Can only find events for subscription creation and subscription deletion only but not for subscription_item.

Read in [here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/pending-updates) that `customer.subscription.updated` event with `pending_update` tag can be used to get notified about creation of a subscription_item, but not able to find any reference to handle subscription_item deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You listen to the `customer.subscription.updated` event.

It contains a Subscription object in the Event object with the "new" updated Subscription. It will also have a `previous_attributes` hash in the response, which would be the diff between what fields changed in order to update the Subscription.

e.g. if I delete a SubscriptionItem from a Subscription, it shows up in the `previous_attributes` hash.

Comment: Hi @hmunoz, thanks a lot for the response, i will try this out and update here.